# Getting the picture from my api to load reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this as my render function and I'm trying to pass the "{this.state.poster}" through it so it will load what ever random film poster it has received from the api. the console.log will show as /q2Y2EuDSaNCH88ETlyiu8bZc5TT.jpg for example but when I try to add that to the image with {this.state.poster} it doesn't work and im not sure why.

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.poster);
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <h1> Lets see what you got</h1>
      <div name="title">
        {this.state.title}
      </div>
      <div name="overview">
        {this.state.overview}
      </div>
      <div name="poster_path">
      <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.state.poster}" alt="picture" />
      </div>
      <div name="vote_average">
        Vote:{this.state.vote}
      </div>
        <button onClick={this.getFilm}>Get Random Movie</button>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" Perhaps you can share what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get? Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${expression}` syntax is meant to be used in [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

What you want here is to concatenate the state with the beginning of the image url like this :

```
<img
  src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/' + this.state.poster} 
  alt="picture"
/>
```

---

or by using a method like

```
getImgUrl (image) {
  return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/' + image;
}
```

and using it with

```
<img
  src={this.getImgUrl(this.state.poster)} 
  alt="picture"
/>
```

Comment: Or you can use the tilda `` quotations to create the string like so: tilda`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.state.poster}`tilda.  I'm having trouble escaping the tilda character on SO, so just replace the word tilda with `

Comment: ```<img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.state.poster}`} alt="picture" />```

Comment: Indeed, this is why I said it in my first statement :)

Answer (score 1):

first the curly brace specifying a js expression then string interpolation :)

`` <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.state.poster}`} alt="picture" /> ``

string interpolation only works inside js expressions ;).

Answer (score 0):

You say that console.log prints out `/q2Y2EuDSaNCH88ETlyiu8bZc5TT.jpg`.

There is a backslash as the first character.

That tells me that the src attribute's value will be `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//q2Y2EuDSaNCH88ETlyiu8bZc5TT.jpg`.

Note, the // to the right of `original`.

Try removing the extra backslash like following:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${this.state.poster}
```